# Finding unique rows in SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm looking at the example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx

```
string s = "primaryKeyValue";
DataRow foundRow = dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"].Rows.Find(s);

if (foundRow != null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(foundRow[1].ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("A row with the primary key of " + s + " could not be found");
}
```

They don't specify where does `dataSet1` come from and does this represent some database?

I'm trying to use this example in my code to find unique rows but I can't seem to implement this syntax. I'm only using connection string to open connection to SQL and I use `SqlDataAdapter` to perform functions...

EDIT:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=Dashboard; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

try
        {
            //Opens the connection to the specified database
            myConnection.Open();

            //Specifies where the Table in the database where the data will be entered and the columns used
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DashboardLibAnswer(Id,Date,Time,Question,Details,Answer,Notes,EnteredBy,WhereReceived,QuestionType,AnswerMethod,TransactionDuration)"
                + "VALUES(@Id,@Date,@Time,@Question,@Details,@Answer,@Notes,@EnteredBy,@WhereReceived,@QuestionType,@AnswerMethod,@TransactionDuration)", myConnection);

            //Specifies the columns and their variable type where the data will be entered
            //Special note:  Conversion from String > DateTime will cause exceptions that will only import some part of data and not everything
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Question", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Details", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EnteredBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WhereReceived", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuestionType", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AnswerMethod", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TransactionDuration", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

            //Using the global variable counter this loop will go through each valid entry and insert it into the specifed database/table
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                //Iterates through the collection array starting at first index and going through until the end
                //and inserting each element into our SQL Table

                DataSet dashboardDS = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dashboardDS, "DashboardLibAnswer");

                DataTable dt = dashboardDS.Tables["DashboardLibAnswer"];

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.Unique)
                    {
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Id"].Value = collection.getIdItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = collection.getDateItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Time"].Value = collection.getTimeItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Question"].Value = collection.getQuestionItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Details"].Value = collection.getDetailsItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Answer"].Value = collection.getAnswerItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Notes"].Value = collection.getNotesItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@EnteredBy"].Value = collection.getEnteredByItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@WhereReceived"].Value = collection.getWhereItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@QuestionType"].Value = collection.getQuestionTypeItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@AnswerMethod"].Value = collection.getAnswerMethodItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@TransactionDuration"].Value = collection.getTransactionItems(i);
                        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                //Updates the progress bar using the i in addition to 1 
                _worker.ReportProgress(i + 1);

            } // end for

            //Once the importing is done it will show the appropriate message
            MessageBox.Show("Finished Importing");

        } // end try
        catch (Exception exceptionError)
        {
            //To show exceptions thrown just uncomment bellow line
            //rtbOutput.AppendText(exceptionError.ToString);

        } // end catch

        //Closes the SQL connection after importing is done
        myConnection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: It's a DataSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806166/how-to-create-sql-connection-with-c-sharp-code-behind-access-the-sql-server-the) question out, and look for the accepted answer. that "tutorial" could be very useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you populate a dataset from your data adapter, you'll be able to follow the same logic - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.71).aspx

It might be worth showing what you actually have to get more specific help

EDIT
I think I'm understanding what you want - if you fill your datatable from the already populated table, just check the item doesn't already exist before adding it - i.e.

```
if (dt.Rows.Find(collection.getIdItems(i)) == null)    
{
    // add your new row
}
```

(just to be sure I knocked together a quick test  - hopefully this helps):

```
  // MyContacts db has a table Person with primary key (ID) - 3 rows - IDs 4,5,6
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MyContacts; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Person", myConnection);

        myConnection.Open();

        DataSet dashboardDS = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dashboardDS, "Person");

        dashboardDS.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new[] { dashboardDS.Tables[0].Columns["ID"]}; 

        List<int> ids = new List<int> {4, 6, 7};

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            if (dashboardDS.Tables[0].Rows.Find(id) == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("id not in database {0}", id); //i.e. 7
            }
        }
```

Comment: Says this when i try the above "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to boolan"

Comment: Thanks, I will try this first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Still not having any luck with this as its not doing what I need it to do : (

Comment: did you update your code to select the contents of your table first (as per the example I put)?  If so, do the IDs in the db definitely match those from your collection?

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to open a connection to your database. This is an excellent source for connection strings: [The Connection String Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Then you will need to fill the dataset with data from some table. Since we are only interested in the schema information we are only selecting one row (`SELECT TOP 1 ...`).

Then we can go through the columns and check their `Unique` property (Boolean):

```
string connString =
            "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
string sql = @"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AnyTable";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet()) {
        da.Fill(ds, "AnyTable");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["AnyTable"];
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
            if (col.Unique) {
                Console.WriteLine("Column {0} is unique.", col.ColumnName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Sorry, I missunderstood your question. The above example returns unique columns, not unique rows. You can get unique (distinct) rows by using the `DISTINCT` keyword in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM AnyTable
```

You can then fill the data table the same way as above.

Usually the word "unique" is used for unique constraints and unique indexes in database jargon. The term "distinct" is used for rows which are different.

---

**UPDATE #2**

Your updated question seems to suggest that you don't want find unique rows, but that you want to insert unique rows (which is the exact opposite).

Usually you would select distinct items from a collection like this. However it is difficult to answer your question accurately, since we don't know the type of your collection.

```
foreach (var item in collection.Distinct()) {

}
```

---

**UPDATE #3**

The easiest way to insert distinct values in the SQL Server table is to filter the rows at their origin, when reading them from the CSV-File; even before splitting them.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Data\MyData.csv");
string[][] splittedLines = lines
                .Distinct()
                .Select(s => s.Split(','))
                .ToArray();
```

Now you have distinct (unique) splitted lines that you can insert into the SQL Server table.

Comment: I've tried this.  The program executes fine but SQL Table does not get updated.

Comment: Is there any way you can help me with the code as this is all new to me.  That would help me out a lot.  My code is up in the original post under EDIT.

Comment: You are asking about finding rows but your new code example inserts rows. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Sorry must have mistyped it.  Basically what I'm doing is I read from .CSV file which gets delimited and each of the delimited elements is stored into the array.  After the array has been updated I iterate through it and insert all of the elements from it into the SQL Table.  This has worked fine, but now I'm looking to only insert unique rows into the Table since the array sometimes contains the duplicates and I want to skip those.  Thanks again.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Finding unique rows in SQL Server Table!