# How do I connect a cshtml to a offsite database server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a group project using MVC and I am trying to get the Orders view to connect to our database which is on an offsite server.

The few tutorials I have seen concerning incorporating a database with a ASP.NET MVC project talks about adding the code

```
var db = Database.Open("nameofdatabases");
```

My problem is that when I start to type Database, the little drop down menu showing what options are available does not show it, DataBindings is the closest it gets.

Also, someone had showed us another line of code:

```
public VivaceContext db = new VivaceContext();
List<Distributor> list = new List<Distributor>();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ist = db.TableName.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldName == "").Orders.ToList();
    var i = db.TableName.Where(x => x.FieldName == "").ToList();
    return View();
}
```

What I am needing to do is retrieve information from several tables in a database at a different location, add data, edit data, and delete data.

Comment: Not sure what tutorials you are talking about, but consider reading http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806166/how-to-create-sql-connection-with-c-sharp-code-behind-access-the-sql-server-the . Note that generally reading data from view (cshtml) is not an ideal approach - consider reading/changing data in controller instead.

Comment: The best option I believe is to add a WebApi to your project which connects to whatever database you want, and then connect to the webapi using pure Jquery ajax call.

Comment: Which WebApi would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this Using **Model**.
Create a Context Class For Each and Every Database which you want to use.
Then Create Strongly Type **Controller** For your Table it will allowed to do all **CRUD** operation on that table.

Comment: So that context class that I mentioned in my question should appear in the models and not the controller?